# Inheriting an explicit constructor (Intel C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, using-declaration, icc, explicit-constructor

Intel C++ compiler (Version 16.0.3.207 Build 20160415) seems to drop the *explicit* specifier when the constructor of the base class is inherited with *using*. Is this a bug?

```
struct B
{
    explicit B(int) { }
};

struct D : B
{
    using B::B;
};

B b = 1; // Not OK, fine
D d = 1; // Not OK with Microsoft C++ and GCC, but OK with Intel C++
```

Comment: This is certainly supposed to be a bug. Inherited constructors are just exposed with the "using" directive so it should be right the same call as in the base class.

Comment: The only thing I found, besides the definition of what an explicit constructor is: "If a using-declaration names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly declares a set of constructors in the class in which the using-declaration appears (12.9)" That's it. I see nothing explicit (pun not intended) that suggests one or the other behavior is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the appropriate wording from the standard is the following (n4296, *12.9 Inheriting constructors*):

> ...
>
> **The constructor characteristics** of a constructor or constructor template are
>
> (2.1) — the template parameter list (14.1), if any,
>
> (2.2) — the parameter-type-list (8.3.5), and
>
> (2.3) — **absence or presence of explicit** (12.3.1).
>
> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited
>   constructors other than a constructor having no parameters or a
>   copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is
>   implicitly declared with **the same constructor characteristics**
>   unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in
>   the complete class where the using-declaration appears or the
>   constructor would be a default, copy, or move constructor for that
>   class.
>
> ...

So most probably it is a bug in the Intel C++ compiler.

Comment: N4296 is a C++17 draft. N4140 is almost exactly the current standard. In N4140 there is a (2.4) point in this section

Comment: @M.M what do you mean?

Comment: @haelix exactly what I said ... what did you find unclear?

Comment: @M.M it seemed to me you were implying that the (2.4) point was significantly changing the answer to the question, but without quoting it, which left me wondering. But perhaps not.

Comment: @haelix no it was just evidence to the fact of N4296 differing from N4140 , my comment relates to the claim of n4296 as being the standard