# Inheritance and conditionally explicit constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++20, standards, explicit-specialization

The use case is for a subclass of std::expected, but the following reproduces the behaviour I'm interested in.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct Foo{
  T value;

  constexpr explicit operator bool(){return true;}
  
  constexpr Foo() {}
  
  template<class U=T>
  constexpr explicit(!std::is_convertible_to<U,T>) 
  Foo(U&& v) : value(std::forward<U>(v)) {}
};

template <class T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T>  {
  using Foo<T>::Foo;
}
```

`Bar` inherits all of `Foo`'s constructors, including their "explicitness"

But.

In gcc(12,13)

```
//Foo<bool> foo() {return Foo<int();} //does not compile, as expected 
Bar<bool> bar(){ return Bar<int>();}
//compiles!
```

clang does not exhibit this behaviour; i.e. `Bar` behaves the same as `Foo`, and trying to return `Bar<int>` from a function returning `Bar<bool>` does not compile. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E4xsfnTob)

Adding the constructor--err, explicitly-- to Bar fixes the issue, but doing so for all the many complex constructors in std::expected would be...infeasible.

My question is:

Can someone with knowledge of the standard shed light on whether this is even a bug in gcc, or merely a loophole? At the moment I wouldn't know how to word the bug report.

Finally, can someone help me find a workaround (short of copy-pasting most of `<expected>` into my little subclass)? I'm working with gcc-12,(std=c++23,linux,x64) on this project, clang doesn't support expected, or other features in c++23.

---

#### what i've tried:

```
template<class T>
using Bar = Foo<T>;
```

works, but without the ability to customize Foo, which is the point

```
template <class T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T> {
  Bar()=default;
  template<class...Args>
  Bar(Args&&...args){
    Foo<T>& self = *this;
    self = { std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  }
};
```

gets close, but shifts requirements from constructors to operator=, plus requires a default constructors on T, and doesn't work for constructors with multiple arguments. (std::expected has a few that take tags: std::in_place_t, std::unexpect_t)

I can maybe work around the above, but it's getting farther from a transparent wrapper.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991336/inheritance-and-explicit-constructors) deals with this subject but predates conditional-explicit (c++20)

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495401/inheriting-an-explicit-constructor-intel-c)
Deals with the Intel compiler, and mentions section 12.9 in some version of the standard, which I read as saying that all characteristics of inherited constructors should be the same, which is reassuring.

Other questions with similar keywords don't handle this intersection of conditional-explicit plus inherited constructors

---

#### Edit:

i've found [these](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96848) [bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85251) on the gcc bug tracker which precisely match my situation.

So that answers my first question: yes its a bug, it's on the gcc bug tracker, and the relevant bit of the standard is [namespace.udecl] p13

> Constructors that are named by a using-declaration are treated as though they
> were constructors of the derived class when looking up the constructors of the
> derived class ([class.qual]) or forming a set of overload candidates
> ([over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy], [over.match.list]).

Still leaving this open in the hopes that some workaround can be thought of.

Comment: "*clang does not exhibit this behaviour.*" What behavior does it exhibit?

Comment: @NicolBolas clang shows the same behaviour for Foo and Bar.  added godbolt link and clarified

Comment: `Foo<T> self = *this;` is not doing what you appear to want.  Did you intend to create a reference?

Comment: sorry, yes, typo. that solution doesn't work in quite a few ways, in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug.

```
template<class From, class To>
concept explicitly_convertible_to =  requires {
    static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>());
  };
template<class From, class To>
concept implicitly_convertible_to = std::is_convertible_v<From, To>;
template<class From, class To>
concept only_explicitly_converible_to =
  explicitly_convertible_to<From, To>
  && !implicitly_convertible_to<From, To>;

template<typename T>
struct Foo{
    T value;
    constexpr explicit operator bool(){return true;}
    constexpr Foo() {}

    template<implicitly_convertible_to<T> U>
    constexpr explicit(false) Foo(U&& v) :
      value(std::forward<U>(v))
    {
    }

    template<only_explicitly_converible_to<T> U>
    constexpr explicit(true) Foo(U&& v) :
      value(std::forward<U>(v))
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T>{
    using Foo<T>::Foo;
};
```

when I rewrite `Bar` as the above, the inherited constructors in `Foo` have the proper kind of `explicit`.  And if I add a `static_assert( this is not explicit )` to the `Bar` constructor, it is triggered by the `Bar<int>` to `Bar<bool>`  implicit conversion, yet the conversion occurs implicitly.

```
template <class T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T> {
  Bar()=default;
  template<class...Args>
  Bar(Args&&...args):
    Foo<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
};
```

we can start here to fix your problem.  This, as noted, causes you to lose implicit/explicit flags.  We repeat the trick I used above.

We start off with `is_explicitly_constructible`, which is `is_constructible`.  Now we try to write `is_implicitly_constructible`:

```
template<class T, class...Args>
concept implicitly_constructable_from = requires(void(*f)(T), Args&&...args) {
  { f({std::forward<Args>(args)...}) };
};
```

this invokes copy-list initialization in a concept-friendly context.

```
template<class T, class...Args>
concept explicitly_constructable_from = requires(Args&&...args) {
  { T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
};

template<class T, class...Args>
concept only_explicitly_constructable_from = 
  explicitly_constructable_from<T, Args...>
  && !implicitly_constructable_from<T, Args...>;
```

we can now write our `Bar`:

```
template <class T>
struct Bar : public Foo<T> {
  Bar()=default;
  template<class...Args>
  requires only_explicitly_constructable_from< Foo<T>, Args... >
  explicit(true)
  Bar(Args&&...args):
    Foo<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
  template<class...Args>
  requires implicitly_constructable_from< Foo<T>, Args... >
  explicit(false)
  Bar(Args&&...args):
    Foo<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
};
```

and I think that does most of what you want.

The big thing you'll be missing is `{}` based construction of `Bar`'s (well, `Foo<T>`'s) construction arguments.

Comment: absolutely perfect, thank you.  adding `Bar() : Foo() {}` gives you default construction, and can be reduced to a single explicit(!implicitly_constructible_from...) Bar(Args&&...) constructor

Comment: @shirleyquirk I split it into true/false cases because I was afraid that whatever bug causes the other `explicit(complex statement)` to not  be properly inherited could cause other problems.  Maybe paranoid.

You should also add in code for special member functions (as well as default ctor) -- copy/move ctor needs special handling as well (maybe?  Maybe the default does the right thing).